# How can I update files from one branch to another branch with submodule

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-submodules, rebase

I'm new to git/gerrit

I have two branches one is **master** another one is say **node**. in the master branch, I just added the **submodule** using the command

**git add -b master "URLOfRemoteRepository" libraries/**

But in the submodule, I have to make changes like adding additional files that I developed, and I have to edit some files that are already present in the submodule, so I created a branch called **node**, I have made changes on few files that required to update with the master so I used rebase, it's throwing error like

**error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:**

**I'm using the sequence of commands below:**

I have these two branches
**master** Branch
**node** branch

**git checkout node**

I added the file by creating a libraries folder and I made a few changes in textfile.txt

**mkdir libraries**

**cd libraries**

**touch textfile.txt**

**nano textfile.txt**

I added a few texts

Now I got a folder structure like this

**libraries/textfile.txt**

**git add libraries/***

**git commit -m "FilesToBeAddedToMasterBranch"**

**git push origin node**

**git checkout master**

**git submodule add -b master "URLofRemoteRepository" libraries/**

After the above command, I'll get **textfile.txt** inside the libraries folder ("Remember I'm having **same directory and same file name** in my other branch that is **node**")

**git add .gitmodules**

**git commit -m "NewSubModule"**

**git push origin master**

**git rebase node master**

After the above command, I'm facing an error like
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
libraries/textfile.txt

My requirement is next time if I clone the master repository and give the submodule update command, the submodule contents should be present with my changes in the node branch, if you know something please give me a solution, if I'm going into the wrong direction please guide me on how to do that.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You will get more responses if you learn to use Markdown to format your question, especially code blocks https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help :)

Comment: Gerrit is going to throw in added complexity to your problem, but I'll note that one aspect of submodules that makes people call them *sob*-modules is that they behave very badly if, in some commit `a123456...`, path `libraries/` is a submodule gitlink, and in some other commit `b789abc...`, path `libraries/textfile.txt` is an actual committed file. Don't do this, you'll regret it.

Comment: Hello torek! First of all thanks for your reply , I'm understanding from reply is there is no solution to fix it is that right ?